# Wordpress hit counter for a multisite install

Tags: wordpress

I need a hit counter for a multisite (20+ blogs) Wordpress install. I have tried a couple different plugins but they don't work on a per site basis. Can someone suggest one or point to a solution?

Comment: hit counter? are you talking about view counter?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the view counter. You can use this plugin [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postviews/).

Comment: Not really what I need. I just need to know how many times a static page has been viewed. There are no posts since I am not running a blog.

Comment: No, you can count pages as well. Try to read the documentation.